# what is the best way to check a file's existence and file permissions in linux using c++

Tags: c++, boost

I am using `boost::filesystem::exists()` to check file's existence.

Is there a better way to do it?

Also how do I find file permissions ?

Comment: you are having any problems while using `boost`?

Answer (score 19):

The only *correct* way to check if a file exists is to try to open it. The only *correct* way to check if a file is writable is to try to open it for writing. Anything else is a race condition. (Other API calls can tell you if the file existed *a moment ago*, but even if it did, it might not exist those 15 nanoseconds later, when you try to actually open it, so they're largely useless)

However, *if* you want to know if a file exists without opening it, simply use the `boost::filesystem::exists` function. But be aware of the gaping flaw in it. It doesn't tell you if the file exists, it tells you if the file *existed*.

So be careful how you use it. Don't assume that just because the function returned true, that the file will exist when you actually try to open it.

If you need to know "will I be able to open this file", then the *only* way to find out is to try to open it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think boost filesystem will give you any info about permissions.

I'd go for the *low level* way (which is anyway really simple, for this case): use the POSIX C API to check for file existence and permissions: use `stat.

---

An example:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct stat sb;

    if( stat("file", &sb) == -1 ) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't stat(). Cannot access file, could assume it doesn't exist" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Permissions: " << std::oct << (unsigned long) sb.st_mode << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Running it:

```
$ ./stat 
Couldn't stat(). Cannot access file, could assume it doesn't exist
$ touch file
$ ./stat
Permissions: 100644
```

Comment: That's great, except that it doesn't always work. It's a huge glaring race condition. What if `stat` says that the file exists, and then, immediately afterwards, it is deleted? What if the permissions are changed between the time when you check, and the later time when you try to open the file?

Comment: @jalf: the OP didn't say what it needs to check the file permissions for. He could even want to write a replacement for `ls`.

Comment: the file permissions check are mostly for the purposes of letting the user why his operation failed

Comment: @user592796: then you should use the error reported by the failed file open function. Otherwise jalf is right: it's possible that immediately after your `open` fails, the file gets replaced by one which could be opened, and your won't know what error to report.

Comment: yes, but it's a pretty important and subtle point, so I just felt it should be mentioned in your answer at least. You're right, there are cases where it is unnecessary. But anyone writing file I/O code should be aware of it.

Comment: You can get (and set) permissions using boost. Use [status](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#status) to get a [file_status](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#file_status) instance, then use the `permissions` method.

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't you just try to open the file with `fopen()` and check if the return value is `null`?

Comment: (Checking if read- or writeable would be possible by changing the `mode`-parameter.)

Answer (score 4):

Using boost is the portable way, of course.

But if you're really interested only in Linux, you can use [access (2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/access.2.html), which will tell you both whether the file exists and whether you can acess it in the way you want (and, without possibly triggering audit alerts).